# Different data with same title and keywords

Tags: seo, keywords

Here is my scenario: I have a website where I redirect my users based upon the device they are using. Let's say a user is visiting from an iPad: I take them directly to the page of iPad wallpapers. The user selects iPad version and I them take them to the gallery of wallpapers where they can select and download any wallpaper. Every wallpaper is the required resolution, I have my reasons for doing this.

Now the thing is there are multiple resolution versions of an image appearing on 5 different sections of my website, each having their own view page. There is only one record in the database table for the image, and based on my consistent naming convention of the images, I pick the required image.

This means when 5 different pages are generated in 5 categorized sections of the website, due to a shared database record, the keywords, titles and every single detail of these is the same besides the resolution of the image, and the section specific details that a page has. The pages also have different paths like

```
wallpapers.com\ipad-1\cars\Ferrari-dino.html
wallpapers.com\ipad-2\cars\Ferrari-dino.html
wallpapers.com\ipad-3\cars\Ferrari-dino.html
wallpapers.com\ipad-4\cars\Ferrari-dino.html
wallpapers.com\ipad-5\cars\Ferrari-dino.html
```

1. ***My question is, how do search engines see it and how do they rank it?***
2. ***Is it a good or normal or bad SEO practice? If bad, how dangerous it is for my site's SEO?***

Comment: Unless you run wallpapers.com, don't use an existing domain for examples. Use your domain, or use example.com or example.org or example.net. Those domains have been specifically set aside for use as examples in documentation. Also, URLs use forward slashes (`/`), not backslashes (`\\`).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad thing, but a more appropriate solution would be one page for the db record, with 5 (or more) download links for the different resolutions.

Because think about your users: someone who is searching for "Ferrari wallpaper" will be confused to discover many pages with same image, the normal convention is one page, and inside it all the required links.

Also, you can dynamically show the appropriate link on this one page. (using javascript/server side detection.. whatever you prefer.)

So you have one url `wallpapers.com\cars\Ferrari-dino.html` and inside it the link to the resolution of the user device.

Comment: see.. normally that would work.. but let us consider the scenario of a device like iPad. iPad doesn't have option to "right-click & save as" & direct links to images is bad navigation, so there has to be leech page and for devices like iPad there will be many leeches...
but i do get your point "appropriate link on this one page"

Comment: You can solve it in many ways, one option is to create a page that when accessing to it the image is downloaded automatically. this way the direct link navigation is not so bad idea.